# Adding a parameter to the links with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to bind variable to every link on my page using java script.
For example:
this string -> ?cid=701a0000000aqBx&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc
should be bind to every link in my page

page1.html?cid=701a0000000aqBx&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc

page2.html?cid=701a0000000aqBx&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc

my variable is -> var utms = location.href.split('?')[1]

Comment: replace link href with jquery and add your own params..

Comment: the idea is to use script without edit each link href

Answer (score 0):

Simple example.. Traverse through your links like this (with JQuery):

```
$("a").each(function() {
    var l = $(this).attr("href");

    // Modify link 
    l += "?someparam=some";

    // Set modified link href back
    $(this).attr("href", l);

});
```

or add event binding to your links:

```
$("a").bind("click", function(e) {

  // Prevent link from changing page
  e.preventDefault();

  var l = $(this).attr("href");

  // Modify l

  // Set new location
  window.location = l;
});
```